# Need help getting loop to work with an onkeydown event in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, onkeydown

I need help figuring out how to get the loop to work properly with onKeydown. Right now, I'm having issues where if you press the key once, it outputs 10 message in one go.

```
var i = 0;

do {
    if (document.onkeydown = keyPress) {
        i += 1;
        console.log(i);
    }
} while (i < 5);

function keyPress(m) {

    if (m.keyCode == '38') {
        i
        document.write("you moved North" + "<br>");
        //up arrow

    } else if (m.keyCode == '40') {
        document.write("you moved South" + "<br>");
        //down arrow
    } else if (m.keyCode == '37') {
        document.write("you moved West" + "<br>");
        //left arrow
    } else if (m.keyCode == '39') {
        document.write("you moved East" + "<br>");
        //right arrow
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what your intention of the initial `do...while` loop is, because it's probably not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: This code makes little sense from start to finish, and using `document.write` is just a bad idea, since it will replace the current document completely. You should go look for some tutorials how event handling and DOM manipulation are done nowadays, and maybe try a JS library that helps with the tedius stuff, such as browser compability.

Comment: I was trying to figure a way out for the loop to print the text once per press.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but given your code, document.onkeydown is always going to equal keyPress. Switch:

```
 if (document.onkeydown = keyPress) {
    ...
 }
```

To:

```
 if (document.onkeydown == keyPress) {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: I think this should really a comment rather than answer. You answer still doesn't help much as keyPress is a function not a variable.